# Format of Hierarchical Parent in New Activities for Android studio

Tags: android, hierarchical

I'm adding a second activity to my ANDROID Studio app and it has a field labeled "Hierarchical Parent". I presume that means the activity that's hierarchically the parent of the new activity that I'm adding, such that when the user at the parent activity and does some action that brings up the OTHER activity, the BACK button will bring you back to the prior activity.

But what is the actual format of what I should enter into that field on the "New activities" dialog?

Answer (score 4):

This pouplates the `parentActivityName` attribute of the `activity` tag in AndroidManifest.xml. You can see documentation here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#parent but note that the documentation says it's for **UP** naviation, not **BACK** navigation.

Enter a fully-qualified class name.